# Asking for a personal reference

Tags: communication, references

I intend to ask someone higher up the corporate chain for a personal reference. They have previously spoken very highly of me but I am not directly affiliated with them or their department.

I am very unlikely to see this person face to face so I am left with other forms of communication such as Email or Phone Call.

Which form of communication would be more appropriate? What factors do I need to consider when asking?

Comment: Just walk into their office/work area when they're not slammed and ask them, no big deal.

Comment: Using what mode of communication have they spoken highly of you ? At a usual All hands meet (from a script) OR because  you personally fixed some broken work flow which saved a lot of money OR just a usual mail that goes out in appreciation ? Do they know you by name or just as an email contact.

Comment: What did finally happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, the best would be face to face.but because as you said this cannot happen, then we go to the second best option which is the phone call.
You should be very very very very polite. Like asking for a salary increase.Explain the situation and there are possibilities that ull get the reference. 
I persist in calling because it gives you the advantage that the other person will have to answer fast, and if he/she has a good opinion about you and your job then you will get a positive answer.

Comment: Hi Tony, Welcome to the site! Thanks for providing a good answer that explains what to do AND why you suggest it! Here is an upvote to get the ball rolling!